# Angular CLI in .NET Core and the modification of index.html

Tags: asp.net, angular, angular-cli

I 've created an Angular project in VS 2017 without using Angular template provided by VS. Instead, I used the Angular CLI stuff by applying:

```
dotnet new angular
```

(have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=netcore-cli&view=aspnetcore-2.1).

So far, so good. However, *I have great difficulties in understanding* how the following **index.html**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>angular_cli</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

created by `dotnet new angular` is being converted to that one when the project is run and getting the first HTTP response:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>angular_cli</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

***How the following lines are added?***

```
  <link href="styles.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>      
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood `angular-cli` uses `Webpack` to bundle the js/css files. The html is edited as the part of the build process.

If you want to inspect what exactly is being done to your scripts/html/code/assets you can always [`eject`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject) the `webpack.config.js`, by running `ng eject`.

Remember to commit your changes before running the `eject` command, so you can easily revert it.

Comment: So, is it webpack that modifies `index.html` itself? Are you sure? Moreover, why to revert after running ng eject?

Comment: Yes, it is webpack. `@angular-cli` provides an abstraction over the webpack configuration. You should not edit the webpack.config.js without a good reason. But you can take a look at what is being done by ejecting, and after you are done, you can revert the eject.

Comment: Why reverting the eject? What changes are introduced by that and why not keeping them?

Comment: `ng eject` is no more available from version 6 onwards